# How to run ReactJS from Sublime

Tags: reactjs, console, sublimetext3

I just started to learn ReactJS and use Sublime Text Editor for most purposes, but couldn't find any methods as to how to setup Sublime so that I can run react apps from the Sublime Console like using the key bind "ctrl + B" for running python files
[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpLJS.png)

Or is it not possible to run it directly from sublime and I need to install VS Code?

Sorry for the bad format, I'm new to stack too ;)

Comment: use the terminal

Comment: the one that is built in to sublime?

Comment: just a normal one?

Comment: oh ohk , i thought there was a shortcut built within sublime or an extension. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I mean VSCode is really good. it's probably worth using it anyways